# Maya 2017 Autoselect or export viewport objects

Tags: python, maya, mel

I want to batch select objects in the selected list, how can i do it with python ?

1. Select some object with mouse in 3D viewport or Outliner.
2. take a list from selected objects.
3. And i want to export batch(objects by objects) in the listed items as different files each per object from listed objects.

When i export rsProxy(Redshift Proxy like OBJ) with my script than selected all objects is exporting to same scene. But i want to batch from overall selected objects.

Thnax.
F

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the exact syntax for Redshift, but here is a general example on how you could export object by object in a list. You will end up with a bunch of files, each containing just what you have selected during each iteration of the loop.

```
import pymel.core as pm

# get a list of the selected objects / nodes to export
export_objects = pm.ls(selection=True)

for obj in export_objects:
    # generate unique filepath
    filepath = "C:\some\export\path\{}.obj".format(obj.shortName())

    # select just one of your objects for export
    pm.select(obj, replace=True)

    # use exportSelected for most filetypes 
    # (or the redshift export command in your case)
    pm.exportSelected(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above probably answered your query.

I asked ChatGPT to do something similar. Move all selected objects to 0,0,0, export each file as .rs - in-case it is helpful here it is:

CODE:

// Get the selected objects
string $selectedObjects[] = `ls -selection`;

// Loop through each selected object
for ($object in $selectedObjects)
{
// Get the object name
string $objectName = `match "[^|]+$" $object`;

```
// Move the object to the origin using setAttr
setAttr ($object + ".translate") 0 0 0;

// Construct the export path
string $exportPath = "C:/YourPath/" + $objectName + ".rs";

// Create a temporary group and parent the object under it
string $tempGroup = `group -em -n ($objectName + "_tempGroup")`;
parent $object $tempGroup;

// Export the temporary group as a Redshift proxy file
rsProxy -fp $exportPath -sl $tempGroup;

// Unparent the object from the temporary group
parent -w $object;

// Delete the temporary group
delete $tempGroup;

print("Exported " + $object + " as " + $exportPath + "\n");
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).